# Find what patients have 5 or more of any appointment within a 120 day rolling window

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find what patients have 5 or more of any appointment that does not occur on the same day and are within a 120 day (4 month) period. 
In the example below the only patient that qualifies is 102 for having at least five appointments that are within a four month frame. The frame is a rolling frame so the qualifying period can include overlapping dates forward or backward for a whole year of data.

I have been trying for days to create a query and find a solution but I can't figure it out.  I can get forward or backwards but I can't figure out how to get a query that covers a moving window. All five treatment appointments must exist within a 120 period window for the patient to be considered qualified.

I have simplified a table called Appointments:

```
AppointmenDate  PatientID 
2015-01-01      101
2015-01-02      101
2015-01-03      101
2015-03-07      101
2015-03-04      101             
2015-03-04      102 *
2015-05-04      102 *
2015-06-04      102 *
2015-07-04      102 *
2015-07-05      102 *
2015-11-04      102
2015-11-04      102
2015-12-12      103
```

The result would look roughly like this (a list of qualified patients):

```
PatientID Qualified
102         yes
```

My best effort is the following:

```
SELECT Distinct a.PatientID
    ,Qualified = 'yes'
FROM Appointments a
JOIN Appointments b ON a.PatientID = b.PatientID
    AND (b.AppointmenDate < DATEADD(day, 120, a.AppointmenDate)
    OR b.AppointmenDate > DATEADD(day, 120, a.AppointmenDate))
WHERE a.AppointmenDate > '2014-12-01' 
GROUP BY a.PatientID
    ,a.AppointmenDate
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
    order by PatientID
```

Comment: Google and learn about the GETDATE() function in SQL, and either the DATEADD() or DATEDIFF() functions.   Use them in your WHERE clause to create a moving window.

Comment: What did you try? Please show your efforts

Comment: Define "day". Is it the number of hours or an actual time at which a day starts and ends?

Comment: Thanks Michael. I added the last query I tried. @Joe it is an actual day. I am using 120 days to roughly represent 4 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the most efficient way of getting the data, but it should fetch what you want:

```
WITH Per AS (
    SELECT A.PatientID, MIN(A.AppointmenDate) MinDate, MAX(A.AppointmenDate) MaxDate, COUNT(DISTINCT A.AppointmenDate) Cnt
    FROM Appointments A
    GROUP BY A.PatientID
)
SELECT Per.PatientID
FROM Per
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, Per.MinDate, Per.MaxDate) <= 120 
    AND Cnt >= 5
```

[edit]
It looks that it can be done in a simpler query, but I have to repeat the aggregate functions (which I do not like):

```
SELECT A.PatientID, MIN(A.AppointmenDate) MinDate, MAX(A.AppointmenDate) MaxDate, COUNT(DISTINCT A.AppointmenDate) Cnt
FROM Appointments A
GROUP BY A.PatientID
HAVING DATEDIFF(day, MIN(A.AppointmenDate), MAX(A.AppointmenDate)) <= 120 
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT A.AppointmenDate) >= 5
```

However, execution plans are the same (might be irrelevant for such small data).